# my flash swf cant detect event.COMPLETE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have a flash file, containing 2 scene.
first scene have continuous looping of random selected external flv file, using flvplayback.
second scene contain code for 2 external swf file, play after another. continuously.

however, it seem dont work for the second scene. it just wont get into the function.
here, i also paste down actionscript code for scene 2.

```
stop();

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("loader.swf"); 
myLoader.load(url);                                     
addChild(myLoader);

stage.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,playnextswf);

function playnextswf(event:Event):void{
    trace("in function");
    removeChild(myLoader);
    var myLoader2:Loader = new Loader();                     
    var url2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("intro.swf"); 
    myLoader.load(url2);                                     
    addChild(myLoader2);    
}
```

> EDIT

i do some editing, by change this line of code:

> .addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,playnextswf);

to

> myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,playnextswf);

it seem to jump into function, but with error.

```
in function
in function
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at praperkahwinan_fla::MainTimeline/playnextswf()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking more for:

```
 var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
 var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("loader.swf"); 
 myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, playnextswf );
 myLoader.load(url);                                     
 addChild(myLoader);
```

You attached the listener to the stage loaderInfo which works a little differently, from adobe:

> The LoaderInfo class provides information about a loaded SWF file or a
>   loaded image file (JPEG, GIF, or PNG). LoaderInfo objects are
>   available for any display object. The information provided includes
>   load progress, the URLs of the loader and loaded content, the number
>   of bytes total for the media, and the nominal height and width of the
>   media.

As we discussed in chat you are looking for something more like this:

```
var myLoader:Loader= new Loader();
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete );
myLoader.load( new URLRequest( "loader.swf" ) );

var myLoaderSwf:MovieClip;

function onLoaderComplete( e:Event ):void {
    trace( "first swf loaded" );
    myLoaderSwf = e.target.content as MovieClip;
    addChild(myLoaderSwf);
    myLoaderSwf.addFrameScript( insert frame number, loadNextSwf );
    myLoaderSwf.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function loadNextSwf():void {
    trace( "removing currently loaded swf -- loading next swf" );
    removeChild( myLoaderSwf );
    myLoader = new Loader();
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onIntroComplete );
    myLoader.load( new URLRequest( "intro.swf" ) ); //change this to intro.swf
}

function onIntroComplete( e:Event ):void {
    trace( "intro swf loaded" );
    myLoaderSwf = e.target.content as MovieClip;
    addChild(myLoaderSwf);
}
```

Comment: is the order making any different? sorry, but i totally noob.. haha. seriously. pls tell me

Comment: Well having the listener added before you do the `load()` is a best practice. `load()` works asynchronously therefore it is possible for you to load the content before the listener is added even if most of the time this is not the case. But more importantly, I didn't put the listener on the stage loaderInfo, it's on the loader `myLoader` which is the object making the file requests, not the stage.

Comment: oic.. ty for explaining. i will do so in every of my code for now on.
i change the code. however, i having a problem with removeChild(). could u help me? i edited my question by putting error log i got there.

Comment: Ok now you have changed your question into a different unrelated error. Try `myLoader.parent.removeChild(myLoader)`.

Comment: hahaha sorry about tht. but are your sure 
"myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, playnextswf );" work?
i try it and find out that code jump into function before the first swf start play.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that it is working, also I'm sure that is the correct implementation. I am also pretty sure you are having multiple issues here that are all unrelated. First, which swf are you wanting to "play" exactly.

Comment: first , loader.swf. after that finish, it should play intro.swf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46715/discussion-between-bennett-yeates-and-dwerty-weird)